# Find the number of needles in a haystack

Tags: php, strpos

I need to find the number of times a needle appears in a haystack. Until this point I've put together the following code:

```
<?php

$haystack = 'http://www.google.com';
$needle = 'a';
$contents = file_get_contents($haystack);

?>
```

I want to find the number of times 'a' (the needle) appears in $contents (haystack - google.com's source code).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this exact same question for the online CSC Waterloo course at http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/

```
needle = 'sses'
haystack = 'assesses'
count = 0
if needle in haystack:
    index = haystack.index(needle)
    string1 = haystack[index:len(needle) + index]
    for position in range(0,len(haystack)):
        if haystack[position:len(needle) + position] == string1:
            count += 1
print (count)
```

...output is 2.

For
an
trans-Panamanian banana ...output is 6

For
o
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis ... output is 9